# Image wont display in ReactJS because of path from local storage

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I am currently trying to display an image using React and using local storage from my pc, not on server for now. Basically, I want to call the pictures that I uploaded, and the filename is already saved inside PostgreSQL database. What I want to do is having a path (my local storage path) that will allows me to render the image. I know we can import pictures at the top using "import .. from *image-filepath*", but the filename changes according to the user assigned on the database.

Is there any other way for me to execute this? Thank you very much!

**File Structure**

```
main folder
  -public
    -uploads
       -location of the image
```

Comment: if your images is in the public folder, you can just use <img src='./image.jpg /> or give variable to name and change it depends on who is logged in

Comment: Yes but the image won't load unless I have it imported at top using this example. E.g: _import pictures from "../../images/uploads/image-user-1.jpeg";_ I wanted to make it dynamic according to the current user logged in. But it seems only the import would work and render the image. @aktoriukas

Comment: The import would only allow me to have only one absolute filename and I couldn't change it for other images, which should load based on the user filename. @aktoriukas